# `pip install mysql-python` fails with " ld: library not found for -lssl"

Tags: python, mysql, ssl, pip

Running `pip install mysql-python` fails with:

```
cc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -Wl,-F. build/temp.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/_mysql.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.13/lib -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/_mysql.so
ld: library not found for -lssl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

I assume this is some SSL library that hasn't been installed correctly.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

You need to find if you have openssl libs and where they located:

```
sudo find / -name "openssl"
```

I got it here:

```
ls -lA /usr/local/opt/openssl/
total 1080
drwxr-xr-x   3 _  admin     102 May 25 14:55 .bottle
drwxr-xr-x   3 _  admin     102 May 25 14:55 .brew
-rw-r--r--   1 _  admin  497920 Jul 16 16:36 CHANGES
-rw-r--r--   1 _  admin     772 Jul 16 16:36 INSTALL_RECEIPT.json
-rw-r--r--   1 _  admin    6281 May 25 14:55 LICENSE
-rw-r--r--   1 _  admin   34649 May 25 14:55 NEWS
-rw-r--r--   1 _  admin    3282 May 25 14:55 README
drwxr-xr-x   4 _  admin     136 Jul 16 16:36 bin
drwxr-xr-x   3 _  admin     102 May 25 14:55 include
drwxr-xr-x  10 _  admin     340 May 25 14:55 lib
drwxr-xr-x   3 _  admin     102 May 25 14:55 share
```

And to install python package you will need to use:

```
env LDFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" pip install MySQL-python
```

Comment: Or `brew info openssl` which reports: "For compilers to find this software you may need to set:
    LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
    CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"